# Why am I getting org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; Content is not allowed in prolog?

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, sax

I am trying to parse an xml file but it continuously goes into exception. I have looked here in for some solution as many had almost same problem as me but it was in vain. The request and response seems to be correct and I have checked my xml and I am not able to find anything wrong in it.

Here is my Java code:

```
             public static void main(String args[])
             {
                SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
                SOAPConnection soapConnection = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();

                // Send SOAP Message to SOAP Server

                String url = "https://sync-test.severa.com/webservice/S3/API.svc";
                SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(createSOAPRequest(), url);

                XMLTransform(soapResponse.toString());
             }

             private static SOAPMessage createSOAPRequest()
             {
             MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
            SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();
            SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();
            String serverURI = "http://soap.severa.com/";
            // SOAP Envelope
            SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
            //SOAP Header content
            SOAPFactory soapFactory = SOAPFactory.newInstance();
            SOAPHeader header = soapMessage.getSOAPHeader();
            Name headerName = soapFactory.createName("WebServicePassword", "ns1", serverURI);
            SOAPHeaderElement headerElement = header.addHeaderElement(headerName);
            headerElement.addTextNode("uheyhd80984023984209380");


            // SOAP Body

            SOAPBody soapBody = envelope.getBody();
            //Create GetAllInvoiceStatuses
            Name name = envelope.createName("GetAllInvoiceStatuses", "ns1", serverURI);
            SOAPElement child = soapBody.addBodyElement(name);
            child.addNamespaceDeclaration("ns1", serverURI);
            MimeHeaders headers = soapMessage.getMimeHeaders();
            headers.addHeader("SOAPAction", "http://soap.severa.com/IInvoiceStatus/GetAllInvoiceStatuses");

            }

            private static void  XMLTransform (String xml) {
            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(xml.toString()));
             Document document = builder.parse(is); // here is the exception!!

            }
```

Here is the xml response I am getting from the server:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Body>
    <GetAllInvoiceStatusesResponse xmlns="http://soap.severa.com/">
        <GetAllInvoiceStatusesResult 
    xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Severa.Entities.API"      
     xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <a:InvoiceStatus>
        <a:Description i:nil="true"/>
        <a:HasInvoiceNumber>false</a:HasInvoiceNumber>
        <a:IsActive>true</a:IsActive>
        <a:IsDefault>true</a:IsDefault>
        <a:IsPaid>false</a:IsPaid>
        <a:IsReadOnly>false</a:IsReadOnly>
        <a:IsSent>false</a:IsSent>
        <a:IsWaitingPayment>false</a:IsWaitingPayment>
        <a:Name>Utkast</a:Name>
        <a:SortOrder>1</a:SortOrder>
        </a:InvoiceStatus>
        <a:InvoiceStatus>
        <a:Description i:nil="true"/>
        <a:HasInvoiceNumber>true</a:HasInvoiceNumber>
        <a:IsActive>true</a:IsActive>
        <a:IsDefault>false</a:IsDefault>
        <a:IsPaid>false</a:IsPaid>
        <a:IsReadOnly>true</a:IsReadOnly>
        <a:IsSent>true</a:IsSent>
        <a:IsWaitingPayment>true</a:IsWaitingPayment>
        <a:Name>Skickad</a:Name>
        <a:SortOrder>2</a:SortOrder>
        </a:InvoiceStatus>
        <a:InvoiceStatus>
        <a:Description i:nil="true"/>
        <a:HasInvoiceNumber>true</a:HasInvoiceNumber>
        <a:IsActive>true</a:IsActive>
        <a:IsDefault>false</a:IsDefault>
        <a:IsPaid>true</a:IsPaid>
        <a:IsReadOnly>true</a:IsReadOnly>
        <a:IsSent>true</a:IsSent>
        <a:IsWaitingPayment>false</a:IsWaitingPayment>
        <a:Name>Betalad</a:Name><a:SortOrder>3</a:SortOrder>
        </a:InvoiceStatus>
        </GetAllInvoiceStatusesResult>
 </GetAllInvoiceStatusesResponse>
</s:Body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the is XML tags are not properly closed i.e. `<s:envelope>`

Answer (score 0):

SOAPMessage.toString() returns the object id like "SOAPMessage@123456".

You want to use SOAPMessage.writeTo(OutputStream).
Or better yet, directly transform the SOAPMessage as its SOAPParts already implement org.w3c.dom.